# Placing a cheirem on a person

Tags: cherem

Is it possible for a layperson or an important person to put a [cheirem](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herem_(censure)) on another person or does it have to be a Rabbi?

Comment: A person can ban another person, sure... Whether or not that ban is binding or taken seriously is another thing

Comment: [Charem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harem)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One need not be a Rabbi to place someone in Niduy or Cheirem (see Shulchan Aruch [Yoreh Deah 334:34](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%93_%D7%9C%D7%93)). However, there are a number of differences, for example, between a Rabbi's and a student's niduy/cheirem (see Yoreh Deah 334:[15](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%93_%D7%98%D7%95)–[16](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%93_%D7%98%D7%96)).

A person must know what he is doing before placing someone in Niduy/Cheirem. Because **if you do it to someone that doesn't deserve it, you deserve to be put in Niduy** ([Yoreh Deah 334:43](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%93_%D7%9E%D7%92) – 24).

Answer (score 1):

Yes anyone can put someone in *cherem*; it doesn't have to be a rabbi, and not even an important person.

The Rambam writes explicitly ([MT Talmud Torah 6:13-14](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/910980/jewish/Talmud-Torah-Chapter-Six.htm)) that "a student" or "any Jew" can excommunicate someone.

> If a teacher placed a person under a ban of ostracism because of his
>   honor, all of his students are obligated to treat the person in the
>   required fashion. However, **if a student issued a ban of ostracism**
>   because of his honor, his teacher is not obligated to abide by the
>   terms of the ban. Nevertheless, all other people are obligated to do
>   so.
>
> Similarly, when a person is placed under a ban of ostracism because of
>   the nasi, all Jews are obligated to abide by the terms of the ban.
>   However, if a person is placed under a ban of ostracism **because of any
>   Jew**, the nasi is not obligated to abide by it.

See also [6:14](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/910980/jewish/Talmud-Torah-Chapter-Six.htm)

> even if the ban was declared by a **person of the lowest stature in Israel**